# Filling two dimensional array with instances

Tags: python

In one dimension I can make the following list:

```py
models = [LinearRegression() for i in range(100)]

for i in range(100):
    models[i].fit(X[i],Y[i])
```

Now I need to make something like a 2D array/ list-of-lists:

```py
for i in range(100):
   for k in range(20):
       models[i,k].fit(X[i,k],Y[i,k])
```

The problem is I don't know how to make two dimensional array that is filled with instances of `LinearRegression`.

I tried to write a list comprehension but couldn't get it to work:

```py
models = [for k in range(20):(LinearRegression() for i in range(100))]
```

Comment: Use a `numpy.ndarray`. Or else fix your list-comprehension as @Asif shows.

Comment: The syntax for nested lists comprehensions is fully documented : https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this according to your need, this will make 5 row x 10 column 2D array:

```
models = [[1 for i in range(10) ]for j in range(5)]
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```